# Row Wise Iteration Vs Column Wise Iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any performance difference if i traverse a 2D Matrix row wise or Column wise.

e.g.

```
import random
import time

l = []

for i in range(1000000):
    temp = [random.random() for x in range(10)]
    l.append(temp)

start_time = time.time()

for i in range(1000000):
    for j in range(10):
        l[i][j] -= 0

end_time = time.time()
time_taken_row_wise = end_time - start_time

start_time = time.time()

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(1000000):
        l[j][i] -= 0

end_time = time.time()
time_taken_column_wise = end_time - start_time

print(f"ROW WISE: {time_taken_row_wise}")
print(f"COLUMN WISE: {time_taken_column_wise}")
```

In the above code, why the time taken for column wise iteration is greater than time taken for row wise iteration?

I ran it twice and got below results:

First Run:

```
ROW WISE: 3.497559070587158
COLUMN WISE: 4.971074819564819
```

Second Run:

```
ROW WISE: 3.638113021850586
COLUMN WISE: 4.855097055435181
```

Comment: I advise you to have a look at `timeit` for time test. [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)

Answer (score 1):

I get results that are even further apart:

> ROW WISE: 11.901052713394165
>
> COLUMN WISE: 38.32502007484436

I suspect it has something to do with how the rows/cols are laid out in memory, and cache pre-fetching (the "by row" works as the cache pre-fetching mechanism expects, and "by column" jumps back and forth between memory pages).

I'll try to use `perf` to try and get a deeper look...

**EDIT:** OK, I think this confirms it:

**BY ROW**

> ROW WISE: 11.151209354400635
>
> ```
>  Performance counter stats for 'python3 by_row.py':
>
>  1,130,850,390      cache-misses                                                
>  1,102,567,550      L1-dcache-load-misses                                       
>     66,438,701      LLC-load-misses
> ```

**BY COLUMN**

> COLUMN WISE: 39.6846444606781
>
> ```
>  Performance counter stats for 'python3 by_column.py':
>
>  2,842,000,454      cache-misses                                                
>  1,544,974,094      L1-dcache-load-misses                                       
>    305,823,025      LLC-load-misses
> ```

we see significant increase (more than x2) in `cache-misses` (number of memory reads that had to actually go to RAM), this could explain why by-column takes more time.

L1-dcache and LLC can give us a little more info about reads that were successfully served by cache (hence, don't count as cache misses), but may still cause differences, based on which cache was used (closer to L1 the better)

Answer (score 0):

For me, there are about the same.

```
ROW WISE: 2.68672251701355
COLUMN WISE: 2.7386820316314697
```

Do you mean why it isn't EXACTLY the same?
... enthropy?

Code :

```
import random
import time

l = []

for i in range(1000000):
    temp = [random.random() for x in range(10)]
    l.append(temp)

start_time = time.time()

for i in range(1000000):
    for j in range(10):
        l[i][j] -= 0

end_time = time.time()
time_taken_row_wise = end_time - start_time

start_time = time.time()

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(1000000):
        l[j][i] -= 0

end_time = time.time()
time_taken_column_wise = end_time - start_time

print("ROW WISE: %s" % time_taken_row_wise)
print("COLUMN WISE: %s" % time_taken_column_wise)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Adam.Er8 said, the performance difference is due to the way the matrix is stored inside the memory. Depending on the language standard, a matrix can either be stored in row-wise, column-wise, or unspecified (depending on compiler implementation).

**For a matrix**

```
11, 12, 13
21, 22, 23
```

**Row-wise** storage would be `[11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23]`

**Column-wise** storage would be `[11, 21, 12, 22, 13, 23]`

Depending on how you access the indices, you can have either sequential or random access. Sequential access accesses the matrix in the successive memory location, while random access jumping from location to location. Therefore, random access has a high cache miss frequency and a high page fault frequency when the matrix gets big enough.

Knowing how a language (and a compiler) access a matrix is critical to the software performance. Simply changing the way the indices are accessed can have up to 14 times difference! (Compiler: g++ o3, matrix size 500 with 2 indices)